# OpenCV program crash when modifying array?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to find the boundary of a sequence of nonzeroes in a row matrix starting from the maximum point and then setting the values outside the boundary to zero.

```
for(int i=maxloc.x; i < 280 ; i++){
    if(!foundBound && sum_r.at<uchar>(0,i) == 0){
        foundBound=true;
        bb.rightEdge = i;
    }
    else if(foundBound){
        cout << i << endl;
        sum_r.at<uchar>(0,i) = 0;     <--- offending line
    }
}
```

But the program crashes when I run it. If I comment out `sum_r.at<uchar>(0,i) = 0;` then the program runs fine until the end. I also got a insufficent memory error once but I can't replicate it. Is there also a better way of accessing the individual elements of a `Mat`?

Comment: what number does the program print out before crashing (result of the line "cout << i << endl;")? are you sure maxloc.x < 280? Are you sure sum_r.cols == 280 ?

Comment: Oops.. that's the problem. I used the number of rows instead. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome. If your question is solved; then please accept the answer so others can see this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program crash indicates that you are probably going outside the boundaries of your matrix. Check the following:

- maxloc.x < 280
- sum_r.cols == 280